# IE11 crashes when started from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, crash, internet-explorer-11, windows-10

I upgraded to Windows 10 and now when I debug my websites from Visual Studio using IE 11, IE just closes.  All I see is in VS's Output [Debug] Window is:
The program '[984] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1073741790 (0xc0000022).
The program '[6600] w3wp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

These lines are after successfully loading several assemblies.

I was using VS 2013.  I uninstalled 2013, cleaned everything up and installed VS 2015 and I'm still having the same issue.

If I use Edge, Chrome or FireFox everything works from VS.  If I start IE using Ctrl+F5 it works. It's only when I choose to debug with IE it fails.

It fails is I use IIS 10 or IIS Express 8.0 to host the website.

IE has better integration so I prefer to use it for general debugging.  How do I fix this?

Comment: 0xc0000022 = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED  or ERROR_WRONG_DISK.  would say it means the first, so try to run VS as admin and see if IE still crashes.

Comment: I already am running VS as admin because on Windows 10 if you want to use IIS you have to run VS as admin, otherwise it fails because it can't access the metadata for IIS on Windows 10.

My gut feel is that Windows 10 messed with a folder's permission somewhere. When trying to repair VS 2013 it kept complaining it didn't have permission for: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\1033.
I found that folder plus others which had no owner and I had to take ownership to fix it.  I think the same may be true with other folders, but don't where to start looking.

Comment: run ProcessMonitor in background while trying to run IE. After you got te error, stop the trace, filter for the error (result column) and look where you get the error. Also maybe the call stack helps to understand it.

Comment: I ran ProcessMonitor and looked through the results.  I saw a lot of "potential" issues, so I compared it to a machine that works fine and saw the similar issues.
Any ideas of what to do next.  I've uninstalled IE and reinstalled it too, with no luck.

Comment: store the trace as PML (unfiltered), zip it, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the link here. I'll take a look at it

Comment: The erros with this log were:
The program '[9696] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1073741790 (0xc0000022).
The program '[7604] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
VS had a PID of 1640.
link: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=298958CA5AE15221!374&authkey=!APVAJTCc93fCm4Y&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: I can't see anything. try to capture a dump (procump -ma -i C:\localdumps or WER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, I tried this and nothing gets written out to the folder.  All I see is IE starting with a blank screen and it then closes right away.
To validate that I set CrashDumps up right, I updated an Adobe plugin and interrupted it.  Then I saw something being written to the CrashDumps folder, so I know it works.
Also I did a repair on VS 2015 and still no joy.

Comment: I'm now out of ideas on how we can solve this.